# How to make the clicks from one UIViewController pass into the parent UIViewController through the hole

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have UIViewController (OverlayViewController), which overlay another UIViewController(RootViewController).

In OverlayViewController I add UIView for all frame size:

```
 var overlayView = new UIView(OverlayViewController.View.Frame);
 overlayView.Alpha = 0.5f;
 overlayView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Blue;
 overlayView.UserInteractionEnabled = false;
 View.AddSubview(overlayView);
```

Then I make a hole:

```
var path = new CGPath();
var radius = 50.0f;
var xOffset = 100;
var yOffset = 300;
path.AddArc(overlayView.Frame.Width - radius / 2 - xOffset, yOffset, radius, 0.0f, (nfloat) (2 * 3.14), false);
var cgRect = new CGRect(0, 0, overlayView.Frame.Width, overlayView.Frame.Height);
path.AddRect(cgRect);

maskLayer.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Black.CGColor;
maskLayer.Path = path;
maskLayer.FillRule = CAShapeLayer.FillRuleEvenOdd;

overlayView.Layer.Mask = maskLayer;
overlayView.ClipsToBounds = true;
```

When I set `overlayView.UserInteractionEnabled = false;` I could touch through OverlayViewController and all clicks worked. 
How I can properly use `UITapGestureRecognizer` so that clicks by items on the RootViewController work only inside the circle? And all the other clicks were blocked.

I tried set `overlayView.UserInteractionEnabled = true;`, but it doesn't help me:

```
tap.ShouldReceiveTouch += (recognizer, touch) =>
{
    return !path.ContainsPoint(touch.LocationInView(overlayView), true);
};
View.AddGestureRecognizer(tap);
```

I use Xamarin, but I can understand the decision on Swift too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution...
I make custom UIView which can set CGPath.

```
public class OverlayView : UIView
{
    public OverlayView(CGRect frame): base(frame)
    {}

    private CGPath _path;

    public override bool PointInside(CGPoint point, UIEvent uievent)
    {
        return _path.ContainsPoint(point, true);
    }

    public void SetPoint(CGPath path)
    {
        _path = path;
    }
}
```

And set `overlayView.SetPoint(path);`.

In OverlayView I override PointInside and check my touch points. Also, I set `overlayView.UserInteractionEnabled = true;`.